# Multiplication of the square root of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

$$
\sqrt{-21+20i}.\sqrt{-21-20i}=\pm(2+5i).\pm(2-5i)=\pm29
$$
But why it is not
$$
\sqrt{-21+20i}.\sqrt{-21-20i}=\sqrt{(-21+20i)(-21-20i)}=\sqrt{|z|^2}\\
=\sqrt{441+400}=\sqrt{841}=29
$$

Does this has something to do with $\sqrt{-a}\sqrt{-b}=-\sqrt{ab}\neq\sqrt{ab},\;a,b\in\mathbb{R_+}$ ?

Where does all these rules coming from ?

Comment: $\sqrt{841}=\pm29$

Comment: @InsideOut for real numbers $\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ we mean the +ve square root, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of complex numbers, it is not a good idea to write $\sqrt z$, since every complex number (other than $0$) has two square roots. So, unless you specify *which* square root you have in mind, the expression $\sqrt z$ is ambiguous. And all you can say about the square root**s** of a product is that **each** of them can be obtaind multiplying **some** square root of the first factor by **some** square root of the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Square root of any non-zero complex number is two valued function since  $(-z)^2=z^2$. In the case of the positive real numbers  (and only in this case) both roots are real numbers. The positive of them is termed principal square root and usually is denoted as $\sqrt x$. To avoid misunderstanding it is therefore advantageous to use $x^\frac12$ instead of $\sqrt x$.

And $841^\frac12=\pm29$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\sqrt(x) = y$ means that $y^2 = x$, so both $y$ and $-y$ would work. However, in case of real numbers, square root is conventionally defined as a non-negative root.

In your case $\sqrt(29^2) = \sqrt((-29)^2) = 29$, so both roots are valid.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}=y\implies x,y\in\mathbb{R}_+$ because $\sqrt{x}$ we mean the +ve(principal) square root

Comment: $841$ has two square roots $+29$ and $-29$ I agree, but $\sqrt{841}$ we mean the +ve square root.

Comment: Only in case of real numbers. With complex, square root typically means “any root”